# Common Layout for two activities - Android

Tags: android, visibility

How Can i have A Singe XML for two Classes? i want to call visibility from                                                 another class, any   help will be highly                                                                           appreciated!

```
    progressBar1 = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
    progressBar2 = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);
    checkBox1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
    checkBox2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);

    checkBox1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            updateProgressBars();
        }
    });

    checkBox2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            updateProgressBars();
        }
    });
    }

    public void updateProgressBars() {

      progressBar1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      progressBar2.setVisibility(View.GONE);

     if (checkBox1.isChecked() && checkBox2.isChecked()) {
        progressBar2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     } else if (checkBox1.isChecked()) {
        progressBar1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     }
```

Comment: You cannot do this with activities. Activities are made to take the whole screen, an entire window. You should try to create a FragmentActivity and then make two Fragment and put into it.

Comment: you're not getting my question. i have Activity A.class and Activity B.class and i have my progressbars and checkboxes in Activity A.xml but due to some reason, i want to call visibility for the checkboxes and progessbars From Avtivity B.class

Comment: @Nikkajihaikjawak but you will be viewing only class `A` or class `B`, if that is the case let me know.

Comment: yes i want to View only Activity A.XML

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling Visibility issue with Checkboxes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23041902/calling-visibility-issue-with-checkboxes)

Comment: @VenomVendor is it possible ?